# Restrict textbox in userform to accept date in mm/dd/yy format

Tags: excel, vba

[MY FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNlus.png)I have userform which takes in date e.g `12/12/2019`, Request ID (unique key) and some other fields from the user and as the user clicks the "ADD" button, the entry gets saved in the Excel file. I have used DatePicker to accept dates from the user.

The entries get stored as strings in the file.
The add button works fine.

Also, it has another button, "GET DETAILS" which retrieves the entry DIRECTLY ON THE FORM based on the "request ID".

The problem I am facing is when I want to retrieve entry with request ID e.g 12201 then all the fields, except the date are retrieved and displayed in the textboxes but since date is entered using DatePicker, I cannot retrieve date e.g `12/12/2019` on datepicker.

I am thinking to replace datepicker with textbox to accept user input date but then have to restrict the user to enter date in `MM/DD/YYYY` to maintain uniformity and prevent any errors

Comment: If I were you, I would use three separate textboxes, for dd, mm, and yyyy

Comment: @TimStack have 6 date time pickers!

Comment: I don't follow. Where does the GET DETAILS button retrieve its information from? And what do you mean with "*I cannot retrieve date e.g 12/12/2019 on datepicker*"?

Comment: Please include some of your code in the question so we help you more easily.